# interpolate variable in PowerShell ps1

Tags: powershell, ps1

I want to get a value from command line and interpolate it in the following (this example is running a Perl pp command, but this should be irrelevant):

```
$AppVersion = $args[0]
Write-Output "AppVersion = $AppVersion"

Write-Output "Creating executable"
pp --% -x -g -o C:\AppCreatorWin\$AppVersion\app.exe "C:\app\app.pl"
```

While AppVersion is correctly printed on terminal, it is not interpolated in the following command.

Comment: try to add quotes: `-o "C:\AppCreatorWin\$AppVersion\app.exe"`

Comment: Try using invoke and separate the command and argument list.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7.3

Comment: `--%` is the PowerShell [stop-parsing token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing?view=powershell-7.3#the-stop-parsing-token). It forces PowerShell to pass the remaining part of the command-line literally, without resolving expressions. That's why `$AppVersion` isn't interpolated. Just remove `--%` and it should work, even without quoting. That being said, it is good practice to quote all paths to have one less thing to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

In Powershell, if you have arguments to an executable like this, it is easiest to use Start-Process with or without -Wait switch:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\AppCreatorWin\$AppVersion\app.exe" -ArgumentList "C:\app\app.pl" -Wait
```

Omitting `-Wait` will run the process in the background. See `Get-Help Start-Process` for details.

If it's just a command without arguments then prefixing an ampersand `&` to the command string will do the trick:

```
& "regedit.exe"
```

For interpolated strings you treat as command (line), be sure to guard against code injection.